# Adding new Build Definition in VS2015 Process Editor incorrectly checks for file within TFS-Git repository

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, tfs, build-definition

**Problem**

When the user right clicks on a Build within the 'Builds' menu of the Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2015, and clicks 'Edit Build Definition' they are taken to the Build Definition editor. Within the 'Process' tab, a Process Editor is opened that reads a XAML file and provides the configurable parameters. However, when attempting to add a new Build Definition, the user will receive a number of errors.

If the user clicks the 'New' button within the Process Editor, [a prompt shows like so](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/905593). If the correct Team Project location is selected, and a path is selected, then the user will receive a prompt reading "[The file you selected was not within a Git repository]."

If a manual entry of the 'Path in repository' textarea is attempted, the user will receive the error "[Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]"

**Software**

I am receiving this problem with VS 2015 14.0.25424.00 Update 3 and TFS Server 2013 12.0.30324.0 (Tfs2013.Update2)

**Workaround**

At the moment, there does not seem to be a fix. I believe that this may be a bug in Visual Studio 2015, but I'm not quite sure. The only information that I have found is that there could be a workaround by using a different version of Visual Studio.

**Frequency**

From my research, this seems to be an issue that people are encountering fairly often. There is a [Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ba83207-1c0a-4744-b6c5-bf9114e1029c/adding-new-build-process-template-in-tfs-project-brings-up-git-dialog-instead-of-vsts-dialog?forum=tfsbuild&prof=required) thread here that you may see the same issues, and the frequency at which it occurs.

Comment: This seems to be an issue for VS2015 update3, you could submit it here [**Develop Community-Visual Studio IDE**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) which will get quickly response by develop team. For now, as a workaround you could add the build process file using VS2013.

Comment: I have logged the issue here [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/53217/adding-new-build-definition-in-vs2017-or-vs2015-pr.html)

Comment: All done, thank you. I am working with the MSFT Visual Studio IDE team on this. My hope is that it can be resolved for the next VS2017 update.